# search for multiple values in a live search

Tags: javascript, json

I have a live search form on my site that is connected to my json file and lets me search for all the different ingredients in the json data and will display the item and all of its ingredients. However my script only allows me to search for one ingredient at a time. Does anyone know how i could search for, for example, ingredient one and then type in ingredient two afterwards in the search bar to bring up those items?

```js
$(window).load(function(){
        $('#search').keyup(function(){
            var searchField = $('#search').val();
            var regex = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
            var output = '<div class="row">';
            var count = 1;
            $.getJSON('new_cocktail.json', function(data) {
              $.each(data, function(key, val){
                if ((val.cocktails.search(regex) != -1) || (val.ingredient_one.search(regex) != -1)|| (val.ingredient_two.search(regex) != -1)|| (val.ingredient_three.search(regex) != -1)|| (val.ingredient_four.search(regex) != -1)|| (val.ingredient_five.search(regex) != -1)|| (val.ingredient_six.search(regex) != -1)|| (val.ingredient_seven.search(regex) != -1)|| (val.ingredient_eight.search(regex) != -1|| (val.ingredient_nine.search(regex) != -1))) {
                  output += '<div class="col-md-6 well">';
                  output += '<div class="col-md-7">';
                  output += '<h4>' + val.cocktails + '</h4>';
                  output += '<h5>' + val.ingredient_one + '</h5>';
                  output += '<h5>' + val.ingredient_two + '</h5>';
                  output += '<h5>' + val.ingredient_three + '</h5>';
                  output += '<h5>' + val.ingredient_four + '</h5>';
                  output += '<h5>' + val.ingredient_five + '</h5>';
                  output += '<h5>' + val.ingredient_six + '</h5>';
                  output += '<h5>' + val.ingredient_seven + '</h5>';
                  output += '<h5>' + val.ingredient_eight + '</h5>';
                  output += '<h5>' + val.ingredient_nine + '</h5>';
      output += '</div>';
                  output += '</div>';                    
                  if(count%2 == 0){
                    output += '</div><div class="row">'
                  }
                  count++;
                }
              });
              output += '</div>';
              $('#results').html(output);
            }); 
        });
      });
 
 </script>
```